# How to modify a vector in main thread from a another thread in c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates

I am trying to implement a parallel accumulate.

- I have a float vector of 10,000 values.
- I divide it into blocks depending upon number of hardware threads
- Then I sum up the values given by each thread.

below is my code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<vector>
#include<numeric>
#include<random>
#include<chrono>
#include<functional>
#include<algorithm>
//implement parallel accumulate

template<typename it, typename T >
void accumulator (it start, it end, T& psum)
{
   
     psum = (std::accumulate(start,end,0.0f));

}


void generate_data(std::vector<float> & ret)
{
    
    ret.reserve(10000);
    std::default_random_engine gen;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0.0,1000.0);
    for(int i =0; i<10000; i++)
    {
        ret.emplace_back(distribution(gen));
    }
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<float> data;
    generate_data(data);
    float result = 0;
    
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    result = std::accumulate(data.begin(), data.end(), 0);
    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stop - start);
    std::cout <<"value :"<<result<<" Time:"<< duration.count() << std::endl;

    //Threaded execution
    int hardware_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    std::vector<float> partial_sums;
    partial_sums.reserve(hardware_threads);
    int block_size = (std::distance(data.begin(),data.end())+hardware_threads-1)/hardware_threads;
    std::vector<std::thread> thread_list;
    auto startit = data.begin();
    auto endit = data.end();
    for(int i =0 ; i< hardware_threads; i++)
    {  
       endit=startit;
       if(block_size > std::distance(startit,endit))
       {
         endit = data.end();
       }
       else
       {
         std::advance(endit,block_size);
       }      
       //partial_sums.emplace_back(std::accumulate(startit, endit, 0));
       thread_list.emplace_back(accumulator<decltype(startit),decltype(partial_sums[i])>,startit,endit,std::ref(partial_sums[i]));
       startit=endit;
       
    }
    std::for_each(thread_list.begin(), thread_list.end(), std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));
    std::cout<<"Partial sum vector size: "<<std::accumulate(partial_sums.begin(), partial_sums.end(), 0)<<std::endl;
}
```

I am sure that my block division logic is correct this can be verified by executing

```
 partial_sums.emplace_back(std::accumulate(startit, endit, 0));
```

This answer will match this code

```
result result = std::accumulate(data.begin(), data.end(), 0);
```

But when I try executing

```
thread_list.emplace_back(accumulator<decltype(startit),decltype(partial_sums[i])>,startit,endit,std::ref(partial_sums[i]));
```

I get zero. It's like the treads are not modifying the partial_sum vector. This partial_sum vector is suppose to hold partial sum values from other threads.

Comment: Minor caution: [`std::thread::hardware_concurrency()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency) can return 0.

Comment: I haven't worked through the code, but this looks suspicious: `endit=startit; if(block_size > std::distance(startit,endit)) ...`. `std::distance(startit, endit)` will always return 0.

Comment: @PeteBecker Hi Pete I think sliding window is correct as I was able to verify the sums from whole vector accumulate and  spliced vector accumulate. I am facing issues in spawning the thread for each window and returning each blocks respective sum.

Comment: You're calling `partial_sums.reserve(hardware_threads);` when you should probably be calling `partial_sums.resize(hardware_threads);`, since reserve changes the capacity but doesn't change the size of the vector. You then access `partial_sums[i]`, which assumes that `partial_sums` has at least `i+1` elements.

Comment: I think you've missed my point. That code is equivalent to `endit = startit; if (block_size > 0)`. If that's what's intended, fine; but most folks would assume that the call to `std::distance` is there for a reason.

Comment: @Kevin okay let me make the change and get back.

Comment: @PeteBecker you are correct, I will verify that part of the code.